# Using dbms_random.value and sorting by date...Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query which is written in oracle sql:

```
 SELECT  
 "P No","Name","Type","AID","Start","End","Day Ended","Worker","Team","Outcome"
 FROM
(SELECT
 O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_SUBJECT_ID as "P No",
olm_bo.get_name(O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_SUBJECT_ID,O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_SUBJECT_IND) as "Name",
O_QUESTION_SET_APPLICATIONS.QSA_DESC as "Type",
O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_ID as "AID",
O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_START_DATE as "Start",
O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_END_DATE as "End",
TO_CHAR(O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_END_DATE, 'Day') as "Day Ended",
olm_bo.get_org_name(assessment_worker.RES_PARTY_OUN_ID) as "Worker",
olm_bo.get_per_name(assessment_worker.RES_PARTY_ID) as "Team",
olm_bo.get_ref_desc(O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_OUTCOME,'ASM_OUTCOME') as "Outcome"
FROM
 O_QUESTION_SET_APPLICATIONS,
 O_RESPONSIBILITIES  assessment_worker,
 O_ASSESSMENTS
 WHERE
( assessment_worker.RES_REC_ID(+)=O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_ID AND assessment_worker.RES_REC_TYPE (+)='ASM' AND assessment_worker.RES_END_DATE IS NULL  )
 AND  ( O_QUESTION_SET_APPLICATIONS.QSA_ID=O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_QSA_ID  )
 AND  
 (olm_bo.get_org_name(assessment_worker.RES_PARTY_OUN_ID)  =  'TEAM'
  AND
  olm_bo.get_ref_desc(O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_OUTCOME,'ASM_OUTCOME')  IN  ('No Further Action')
  AND
  O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_END_DATE  Is Not Null  
  AND
  O_QUESTION_SET_APPLICATIONS.QSA_ID  IN  ( 'TYPE1'  )
  AND
  O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_END_DATE  >=   trunc(sysdate-7)
)
 ORDER BY
  dbms_random.value)
 WHERE  ROWNUM  <=  30
 ORDER BY "End" DESC
```

Basically it is returning closed assessments which have been closed in the past week, and the dbms_random.value is returning 30 random records.  However, I'd also like to sort the final output in descending order by the end date.  However, this doesn't appear to be working at all, and I guess it's something to do with the dbms_random.value.  I've tried putting the order by "end" above the dms_random.value but that doesn't appear to work either - both examples of code will run, but they don't appear to be returned in any order by date.  Not sure if I'm missing anything blindingly obvious, but any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit:

Bizarrely, this works:

```
SELECT  *  FROM
(SELECT
  O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_SUBJECT_ID as "P_No",
  olm_bo.get_name(O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_SUBJECT_ID,O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_SUBJECT_IND) as "Name",
  O_QUESTION_SET_APPLICATIONS.QSA_DESC as "Type",
  O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_ID as "AID",
  O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_START_DATE as "Start",
  O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_END_DATE as "End",
 TO_CHAR(O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_END_DATE, 'Day') as "Day_Ended",
  olm_bo.get_org_name(assessment_worker.RES_PARTY_OUN_ID) as "Team",
  olm_bo.get_per_name(assessment_worker.RES_PARTY_ID) as "Worker",
  olm_bo.get_ref_desc(O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_OUTCOME,'ASM_OUTCOME') as "Outcome"
FROM
  O_QUESTION_SET_APPLICATIONS,
  O_RESPONSIBILITIES  assessment_worker,
  O_ASSESSMENTS
WHERE
  ( assessment_worker.RES_REC_ID(+)=O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_ID AND assessment_worker.RES_REC_TYPE(+)='ASM' AND assessment_worker.RES_END_DATE IS NULL  )
  AND  ( O_QUESTION_SET_APPLICATIONS.QSA_ID=O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_QSA_ID  )
  AND  
  (nvl(olm_bo.get_org_name(assessment_worker.RES_PARTY_OUN_ID),'NULL')  =  'TEAM'
   AND
   nvl(olm_bo.get_ref_desc(O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_OUTCOME,'ASM_OUTCOME'),'NULL')  IN  ( 'CONTACT ONLY - all actions complete','No Further Action'  )
   AND
   O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_END_DATE  Is Not Null  
   AND
   nvl(O_QUESTION_SET_APPLICATIONS.QSA_ID,'NULL')  IN  ( 'TYPE1')
   AND
   O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_END_DATE  >=   trunc(sysdate-7)
  )
ORDER BY
   dbms_random.value)
WHERE  ROWNUM  <=  30
ORDER BY "End" DESC
```

So no idea if there was a glitch in the original code, or something has been changed to make it work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knocking up a quick example is worked fine, so checking your SQL explicitly, there seems to be a problem in the post due to the edits you made possibly. I've indented it to make it clearer.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
        "P No","Name","Type","AID","Start"
        ,"End","Day Ended","Worker","Team","Outcome" 
    FROM O_ASSESSMENTS 
    WHERE 
     O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_END_DATE  Is Not Null   
    AND 
      nvl(O_QUESTION_SET_APPLICATIONS.QSA_ID,'NULL')  IN  ( 'TYPE1') 
    AND 
     O_ASSESSMENTS.ASM_END_DATE  >=   trunc(sysdate-7) 
   ) 
ORDER BY 
dbms_random.value

) 
WHERE  ROWNUM  <=  30 
ORDER BY "End" DESC
```

That final closing bracket matches nothing, so something is not quite right. Example I threw together:

```
select a.test_id
from
(
select test_id
from tbl_Test
order by dbms_random.value
) a
where rownum <= 10
order by a.test_id
```

Brought back 10 random IDs from an example table in the order specified on the outer ordering.

Comment: I've updated my original question to include the full query, as maybe there's something I stripped out that is causing a problem.  It still looks like in my query there is a rogue bracket to me though, but it's running the query.  If I take out that rogue bracket, I get an error.  Might be that it's getting late, so I'll double check and see if I can figure it out.  Thanks for responding though, at least I know it 'should' work.

Comment: Just to check another 'obvious' one, the End column, is a date and not a varchar?

Comment: I'm starting to think it's something to do with the 'end' column - it is defined as a date, and if I try to wrap it in a to_date I get an error about 'date format picture ends before converting entire input string'.  I know I can just stick a count in there to look at days open and do the order by on that, so that may have to do for now!

Comment: And now...for no reason whatsoever, it seems to be working fine!